# Can spring security answer these needs?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-security

I've read the features a little bit on the site about what spring security offers ..

But i just want to make sure before diving down or even rolling my own simple solution, hoping some confirmations from experienced developers that made use of Spring security.

Im currently developing using jsf2 + primefaces, spring3, jpa2 + hibernate

I have these needs :

1. have the list of users, and groups of users
2. need to authenticate the user on login (this is so basic, it must be supported already)
3. the security system can be configured for modules (packages of the java project or can be seen as menus / programs in the UI), so if user is configured to be able to access all programs in menu 1 and menu 3 and only 1 program in menu 4, then the menu will be displayed only for the allowed, and accessing directly on the unallowed menu / program URL will cause error.
4. need to authenticate user on the service methods (plain java methods) on levels like readonly level, r/w level. So for example, if we can configure that public void save(...) to have the r/w access, only users that's given r/w access can call this method
5. can even extend this on the JSF 2 xhtml, where i can make use of the r or r/w access to enable / disable buttons or links or other stuffs, perhaps programatically using the disabled attribute of a jsf component.
6. would be better if some of these features like authenticating the program or the service methods are done transparently using AOP, without dirtying the business processes codes.

Please share your opinions on this ..

Thank you !

Comment: spring security + JSF 2.0 is a good combination. Go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security would support most of your requirements.

1. You can use the roles for that. For instance: USER, ADMIN, CONTRIBUTOR, etc. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html
2. That you can do with the 
   form-login element nested in the http element in your security configuration. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started
3. On the view side, you can control who sees what using taglibs in you use JSPs. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html Then on the server side, you make sure that whoever made a particular call had the right to do so. You can control at the URL level and at the method level. For instance, for the URL, you have the intercept-url element nested in http. You can protect a method with @Secured annotation
4. Not sure what you mean by read/write for a particular method but as mentioned in #3, you can use an annotation to secure a method
5. Not sure what JSF allows you to do, but if you use JSPs, you can use the taglibs as stated before
6. You *should* be able to do so but I can't provide you with any examples though. I'd like to read from others too on this one.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. About the user roles, can we define our own role ? I would like to have a webapp for the client to be able to create their own users as needed, associate the user to one or more roles, create new roles, associate roles with the programs whether it can do readonly or r/w access. And does spring security support JSF also, since im not doing any JSP anymore for this new project. Thank you !

Comment: When you say "associate roles with the programs", how do you intend to do so? It sounds like you'd like to create dynamic roles (which is fine), but what is your plan for defining that a particular "area" is restricted to a specific role? As for JSF, I'm not sure what it supports right off the bat.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but .. Imagine i have this menu of purchase, sales, account payable, inventory, etc. And each of these menus has menu items or even submenus. And each menu item corresponds to a JSF view. I would like to map for example, that this role or this user can only access menu purchase, but not the sales, and can also access several menu items from inventory menu, but for readonly access only, for example.

Comment: And about dynamic role, im unsure of what the term means. What i had in mind is .. that i have a JSF view to manage roles and users, for example, the purchase role has one or more users, the cashier department has such and such users, etc. And later i can associate the user or role to menu or menu items with it's own permissions (readonly or r/w)

Comment: What you can do is for let's day purchase, you implement 2 methods in your controller, one for viewing/reading (restricted to users with the USER role) and one for editing/writing (restricted to users with the ADMIN role). Then you show the links accordingly so that a user doesn't see a link they're not allowed to click on. Does it make sense?